# iphone - change label with push notification possible?

Tags: iphone, push-notification

Push notification runs this on ApplePushNotificationAppDelegate.m.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

for (id key in userInfo) {
    NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@", key, [userInfo objectForKey:key]);
}

ApplePushNotificationViewController *apns = [ApplePushNotificationViewController alloc];
NSLog(@"%@ changed", [apns labelchange]);
}
```

It goes to ApplePushNotificationViewController.m and does this

```
-(NSString *)labelchange{
label2.text = @"labelchanged";
return @"hi";
}
```

and the result in the console is this without changing the label on my iPhone

```
2011-08-03 18:20:56.501 ApplePushNotification[1473:707] key: acme1, value: bar
2011-08-03 18:20:56.503 ApplePushNotification[1473:707] key: acme2, value: 42
2011-08-03 18:20:56.505 ApplePushNotification[1473:707] hi changed
2011-08-03 18:21:04.347 ApplePushNotification[1473:707] key: aps, value: {
    alert = "You got a new denyapps!";
    badge = 5;
    sound = "beep.wav";
}
```

How come my program runs the program but does not change the label2.text to "labelchanged"?

Need to get certificate to use the push service but here are the links for the projects, "PushMeBaby" is the server.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12439052/ApplePushNotification.zip
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12439052/PushMeBaby.zip

Thanks.

Comment: Where you have initialised your label2? It might not be get initialised so why it is not changing its text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ApplePushNotificationAppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class ApplePushNotificationViewController;
@interface ApplePushNotificationAppDelegate : UIViewController {
UIWindow *window;
ApplePushNotificationViewController *viewController;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <View1Delegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet ApplePushNotificationViewController *viewController;

@end
```

ApplePushNotificationAppDelegate.m

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
        viewController.label2.text = @"changetext";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't calling init on your view controller - only alloc.

```
ApplePushNotificationViewController *apns = [ApplePushNotificationViewController alloc];
```

So your view controller isn't initialising everything.

In your view controller code, you have the labelchange method as

```
-(NSString *)labelchange{
    label2.text = @"labelchanged";
    [self changelabel];
    return @"hi";
}
```

And the changelabel method is

```
-(IBAction)changelabel{
label2.text = @"button";
}
```

So the label's text won't be "labelchanged"

Comment: Post your code for 'ApplePushNotificationViewController.m' and 'ApplePushNotificationViewController.h'

Comment: it's inside http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12439052/ApplePushNotification.zip i wonder if it is even possible...

Comment: yea got that the text should become "button" but the thing is it wouldn't even change it to button because i'm calling the function from a different class, i think it's skipping through all the property and synthesize methods

Comment: Have you tried setting breakpoints in your code and then stepping through to make sure your code is actually being called and to check that your objects are not nil?